# Why I cannot use both ORDER BY and DISTINCT * in SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to do the following, and if I were to uncomment the distinct it will break.  Also if I comment out the order and leave the distinct in, it will work.

```
Contestant.joins('INNER JOIN votes AS V ON V.contestant_id = contestants.id AND V.season_id = '+ season_number.to_s)
                      .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN votes AS XV ON (XV.contestant_id = '+self.id.to_s+') AND (XV.tribal_council_key = V.tribal_council_key) AND XV.contestant_voted_for_id = V.contestant_voted_for_id')
                      .joins('INNER JOIN season_rosters ON season_rosters.season_id = V.season_id')
                      .where('V.is_jury_vote = (?) AND V.contestant_id <> (?) AND XV.tribal_council_key IS NOT NULL', :false, self.id)
                      .order('season_rosters.finished')
                      #.distinct
```

The error I get is below...

```
TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near '*'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT *, __order FROM ( SELECT [contestants].*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY season_rosters.finished ASC) AS __order, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [contestants].* ORDER BY season_rosters.finished ASC) AS __joined_row_num FROM [contestants] INNER JOIN votes AS V ON V.contestant_id = contestants.id AND V.season_id = 6 LEFT OUTER JOIN votes AS XV ON (XV.contestant_id = 112) AND (XV.tribal_council_key = V.tribal_council_key) AND XV.contestant_voted_for_id = V.contestant_voted_for_id INNER JOIN season_rosters ON season_rosters.season_id = V.season_id WHERE (V.is_jury_vote = (''false'') AND V.contestant_id <> (112) AND XV.tribal_council_key IS NOT NULL) ) AS __sq WHERE __joined_row_num = 1 ORDER BY __order'
```

Comment: so your question is basically the (tried and tested) SQL syntax doesn't work the way I want it to? BTW, use of Distinct is often a sign your design or query is wrong.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess I was hoping someone could point out why I cannot use both the `.order` and `.distinct`.  Or any other comment that would be helpful in understanding the problem.

Comment: I do not think you can do a `SELECT DISTINCT *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this part:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, __order
```

Try adding the required columns to your GROUP BY.

```
Contestant.joins('INNER JOIN votes AS V ON V.contestant_id = contestants.id AND V.season_id = '+ season_number.to_s)
                      .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN votes AS XV ON (XV.contestant_id = '+self.id.to_s+') AND (XV.tribal_council_key = V.tribal_council_key) AND XV.contestant_voted_for_id = V.contestant_voted_for_id')
                      .joins('INNER JOIN season_rosters ON season_rosters.season_id = V.season_id')
                      .where('V.is_jury_vote = (?) AND V.contestant_id <> (?) AND XV.tribal_council_key IS NOT NULL', :false, self.id)
                      .order('season_rosters.finished')
                      .group('col1,col2,__order')
```

Also in your SQL error, order by is on a different column while in your code, it is on `season_rosters.finished`.